# Add and remove icon dynamically when the video is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a div where I have list of video URL and I need to add the play icon dynamically, While the video is playing and I need to remove it. While the other video is clicked and add to that video. But I am not able to remove it while other one is clicked.

Here, is my html and script what i have tried so far,

```
    <div class="myDiv" >
    <ul>
    <li class="videoList" id="item-0" >
    <div class="row" href="#video1">
    <div>
    <img class="ImagContent">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label class="myClass">Text</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
<li class="videoList" id="item-1" >
    <div class="row" href="#video1">
    <div>
    <img class="ImagContent">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label class="myClass">Text</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

$('.myDiv').click(function () {
var id=$(this).attr('id')
   $('#'+id).find('.myclass').append('<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf144;</i>');
});
```

Anyone Can help me to resolve this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: do you want to perform action when someone click on li element?

Comment: Once click on the div element itself the video should be played and icon should be displayed

Comment: Your question is not cleared. where is video url? you want add icon before it. Please add html with multiple video. If you don't want to show url just write video_url1, video_url2. So I can easily help you.

Comment: Once again I edited. @Yogendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/*$(".videoList").click(function () {

  $('.videoList').find('.myClass').html(""); // remove icon from  myClass
    $(this).find('.myClass').append('<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf144;</i>'); // append icon 
});*/


$(document).on('click',".videoList",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.videoList').find('.myClass').html(""); // remove icon from  myclass
    $(this).find('.myClass').append('<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf144;</i>'); // append icon 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="myDiv" >
    <ul>
        <li class="videoList" id="item-0" >
            <div class="row" href="#video1">
                <div>
                    <img class="ImagContent">Image 1
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="myClass">Text</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="videoList" id="item-1" >
            <div class="row" href="#video1">
                <div>
                    <img class="ImagContent">Image 2
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="myClass">Text</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


</form>
```

Try the following

```
$('.videoList').click(function () {
    $('.videoList').find('.myClass').html(); // remove icon from  myclass
    $(this).find('.myClass').append('<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf144;</i>'); // append icon 
});
```

you can also use html function

```
$(this).find('.myClass').html('<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf144;</i>');
```

Comment: If you want add any text then use $('.videoList').find('.myclass').html("Text");

Comment: Actually I  used your js script. In html your class name "myClass" and in javascript code you are using "myclass". I checked this now its working. I have given you 2 script. both will work 1 is commented other is not

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$('.videoList').click(function () {
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $('.myclass').html('text'); // set default value for all
    $('#'+id).find('.myClass').append('<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf144;</i>'); // append icon to myClass 
});
```